# Illegal characters in path(Read Description)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, directory, illegal-characters

I'm currently making a folder with a symbol in its name, so I used this code:

```
Private Sub ButtonDirectory_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonDirectory.Click

    FBDPath.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.Text = FBDPath.SelectedPath & "\◯Folder Safe *by Me*◯"
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonCreate.Click
    Dim folderpath As String
    folderpath = TextBox1.Text
    If Directory.Exists(folderpath) Then
        MsgBox("Folder already exist!", vbInformation, "Safe Folder")
    Else
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath)
        MsgBox("succesfull", "Safe Folder")
    End If
End Sub
```

So, after I start the build, I can choose a folder, but when I click create, that's where the problem arises: "Illegal characters in path."

FYI:

- the highlighted problem is "Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath)~"
- FBDPath is FolderBrowseDialog
- there are 2 buttons and a textbox.

Comment: You can't have an asterisk `*` in a file or directory name in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're allowing the user to type stuff in, you should remove any invalid input:

```
Dim pathBits = TextBox1.Text.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)

For Each c as Char in Path.GetInvalidPathChars()
  For i = 0 to pathBits.Length - 1
    pathBits(i) = pathBits(i).Replace(c, "_"c)
  Next i
Next c

folderpath = string.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, pathBits)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a asterisks in your file name: `"\◯Folder Safe *by Me*◯"`.  With windows file naming you have to avoid using the following characters.

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file